# Why Woocommerce variation prices set dynamically through javascript (not manually inserted) don't get saved by woocommerce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have written a plugin in javascript that calculate and insert prices of variations dynamically. Since I can have 120 variation, this solution is very efficient. The plugin works perfectly in calculating the prices and inserting them in the inputs of prices of each variation. The problem is that when I save the variations, pressing the 'save' button, they don't get saved and I find the fields empty after pressing save and waited for saving to end.

I have checked the HTML and the attribute value gets correctly updated by javascript but for some reason woocommerce doesn't realize the variation fields has changed.

Do you have any idea?

===
Code to reproduce the issue:

jQuery(".short.wc_input_price").val(333);

Press 'Save Changes' button, under the variations.

Comment: Please be more specific - question is too broad to be answered as to 'why' something you did (which we have no visibility to) does not work

Comment: My first guess is that you are updating the HTML input fileds but the price WooCommerce sees (or knows about) is the one from the DB - unless you update the prices on the DB as well, WooCommerce will not know about the updated prices at all

Comment: For this kind of question you should include **"the shortest code necessary to reproduce your issue"**… Without that, answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: === Code to reproduce the issue:

jQuery(".short.wc_input_price").val(333);

Press 'Save Changes' button, under the variations.